# sqlite alter table add MULTIPLE columns in a single statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, alter-table

Is it possible to alter table add MULTIPLE columns in a single statement in sqlite?
The following would not work.

```
alter table test add column mycolumn1 text, add column mycolumn2 text;
```

Answer (score 371, accepted):

No, you have to add them one at a time. See the syntax diagram at the top of [SQLite's ALTER TABLE documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html):

[image: ALTER TABLE syntax]

There's no loop in the `ADD` branch so no repetition is allowed.

Comment: @JoshPinter: Thanks but I think the syntax diagrams in the SQLite docs deserve a lot of the credit, the syntax diagrams are great, everyone should use them in their docs.

Answer (score 21):

The only thing so far possible that I use is

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
ALTER TABLE tblName ADD ColumnNameA TEXT DEFAULT '';
ALTER TABLE tblName ADD ColumnNameB TEXT DEFAULT '';
ALTER TABLE tblName ADD ColumnNameC TEXT DEFAULT '';
COMMIT
```

Note that there are ; on purpose to make the query be read as multiple lines.

Then I run this query and get multiple columns added in on run... So no not in one line, but yes in one query its possible.

Comment: Note that the `migrate` method is already called in a transaction so there's limited benefit to this approach.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from '*@mu is too short*' is right. Providing an optimized solution for adding multiple columns using the *transactions* feature in SQL.

```
String alterTableQuery = "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN ";
List<String> newColumns = ..// Your new columns

db.beginTransaction();
for (String column : newColumns){
    db.execSQL(alterTableQuery + column +  " VARCHAR");
}
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

I hope this will help someone.