# SQLITE : How to add several columns to a table?

Tags: sqlite

Hi In my application I am using SQLITE database,

I want to add multiple column in table,

If i am adding one column that work fine,

I am using ALTER table for add new column,

With this i am able to update one column,

```
ALTER TABLE "main"."tblCredit" ADD COLUMN "CardDetail" VARCHAR
```

But How can i add multiple column in `tblCredit` table.

Comment: May be this is duplicated Question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172815/sqlite-alter-table-add-multiple-columns-in-a-single-statement#

Comment: You can't do this as per SQLite Documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use repeated calls to `ALTER TABLE`.

You should not have to do this too often anyway.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But, We can't add the multiple column in one Alter query. Because i want add 5 column than  i have to fire a 5 times alter query.

Comment: Correct. There is no other way. It is quite simple, really. Documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html).

Answer (score 1):

IN DB2 
with the help of alter command add multiple column in table

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN F_NAME VARCHAR(30)
ADD COLUMN L_NAME VARCHAR(30)
ADD COLUMN ROLL_NO INTEGER
ADD COLUMN MOBILE_NUMBER VARCHAR(12);
```