# Laravel table * has no column named *

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, database-migration

My unit tests recently started failing.  I am getting this error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: 
General error: 1 table loan_details has no column named start_month
```

The line where it is happening, I have this code:

```
$loan = LoanDetails::create(['loan_percentage' => .8,
        'loan_product_id' => 1,
        'interest_rate' => .5,
        'start_month' => 0,
        'term' => 120,
        'fixed_finance_fee' => 0,
        'variable_finance_Fee' => 0,
        'valid_from' => '2015-01-01'
    ]);
```

If I comment out the "start_month" line then it logically works.

In the setup of my unit tests I run all migrations (about 80).

I have a migration that looks like this:

```
Schema::table('loan_details', function(Blueprint $table){
     $table->integer('start_month')->unsigned()->after('interest_only')->default(0);
     $table->decimal('balloon_percent',4,3)->after('term')->nullable();
     $table->integer('balloon_month')->after('balloon_percent')->nullable();
     $table->dropColumn('ordinal_rank');
});
```

So, I wondered if all the migrations weren't running so I ran this code:

```
$rows = DB::table('migrations')->get();
print_r($rows);
```

This lists all of the migrations as having completed.  I am using an in memory sqlite db for the tests.

I am wondering if the migrations are run asynchronously and they aren't all finished by the time my code runs?  Or if the migrations are silently failing somewhere?

I've been at this for hours and don't know what is happening.

*UPDATE I have a migration that runs AFTER the above migration, and I confirmed that the subsequent migration was successful.  So it is just this one migration that is silently failing in some way.

Comment: Do you see the migration that adds the column in the list of migrations run?

Comment: Yes, I lists all of them including the one I expect.

Comment: And do you see that column in the database? If there was error when migration was running it might be saved in migrations table even though it was not completed.

Comment: I assume it is not in the database.  I don't know how to check the in memory sqlite db.

Comment: if that's the last migration you could try to roll it back with "php artisan migrate:rollback" and then run "php artisan migrate" to execute it again

Comment: The original migration has run in production.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I found the issue.  It is because of the ridiculous limitation that sqlite has of not having multiple add column statements in one table call as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172815/sqlite-alter-table-add-multiple-columns-in-a-single-statement).

When I separate out the migration as below it works:

```
Schema::table('loan_details', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->integer('start_month')->unsigned()->after('interest_only')->default(0);
});
Schema::table('loan_details', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->decimal('balloon_percent',4,3)->after('term')->nullable();
});
Schema::table('loan_details', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->integer('balloon_month')->after('balloon_percent')->nullable();
});
Schema::table('loan_details', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->dropColumn('ordinal_rank');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helped a great deal. 

It is very disappointing that you cannot use $table->morphs('taggable'); since this creates to columns and an index which will be problematic when unit testing with sqlite.

Comment: Thanks for this. This really helps and works for me.

Comment: I could make tests to check the schema is even correct but it seems ridiculous.
 
$this->assertTrue(Schema::hasColumn('users', 'firstName'), 'Users table does not have a firstName column.');
$this->assertTrue(Schema::hasColumn('users', 'lastName'), 'Users table does not have a lastName column.');
 
I can see the sqlite schema by doing this from a test.
dd(DB::select("SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name;"));

Answer (score 2):

To check SQLite DB records [here](http://sqliteviewer.flowsoft7.com/)

There are many other useful built-in dot commands -- see the documentation at 
http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html, section Special commands to sqlite3.

also, check DB schema