# How can I add new columns to a SQLite database after the Android app is released?

Tags: android, google-play, android-sqlite

I want to add new columns to a SQLite database, but I already released my app on the Play Store so, if I edit it, users need to uninstall and reinstall the app,
but I don't want that. Please, help, I am new to Android.

Comment: look up sqlite migrations. You can update the table structure while keeping data. Can be difficult if you have to move around data.

Comment: If my answer was useful to use, I'll greatly appreciate if you can accept an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to changes in following method of Database Class

```
@Override 
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String sql = "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_SECRET + " ADD COLUMN " +
     "name_of_column_to_be_added" + " INTEGER"; 
    db.execSQL(sql);        
}
```

Comment: Your database will not lose data. Reminder: onUpgrade will be called when getWriteableDatabase or getReadableDatabase is executed AND the version of your database is different from your older version.

Comment: do one thing uninstall application and re-install.from then open Device file explorer option menu in android studio push db file  and match column name

Answer (score 9):

(1) Increment (or simply change) your database version
(2) It would lead to `onUpgrade()` method call 
(3) Execute your query(for adding a new column) in the `onUpgrade()` method.

The Right Way of doing is mentioned [here in this blog](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/how-android-sqlite-onupgrade).

Sometimes user may update the version 1.5 from the version 1.1.In other words, They may skip the other versions between the 1.1 to 1.5. You might changed database couple of time between 1.1 to 1.5. So in order to give the user a benefit of all the database changes, you need to take of onUpgrade() method as below.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   if (oldVersion < 2) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_1);
   }
   if (oldVersion < 3) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_2);
   }
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks,but i have another table i have to write anything in onupgrade method for that table

Comment: As you haven't mentioned about the table and all, this is a generic answer which exactly matches to your question. You simply need to replace your query based on your requirements in the onUpgrade() method. I have also mentioned a blog that does the same.

Comment: Didn't get your question. You want to add column to the existing table right? For this, you don't need to write the onCreate again in the onUpgrade. Simply use the query in the onUPgrade to update your table - ALTER TABLE your_table_name  ADD COLUMN your_new_column_name TEXT - I have simply considered the new column type TEXT. You should change it according to your requirements.

Comment: You are receiving the SQLiteDatabase instance (db), So simply write this line - db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD COLUMN your_new_column_name TEXT)

Comment: thanks for your responce bro my qst  is i have four tables in my database i want to add three coloums to only one table

Comment: thanks for your responce bro my qst  is i have four tables in my database i want to add three coloums to only one table for that the above code is okay but for remaining tables i have to write any code in on upgrade like ( db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ProductSales);)

Comment: With SQlite, you cannot add three columns with a single query. Please visit this for more information - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6172889/6306365. Simply Call the db.execSQL three time in the onUpgrade()

Comment: You don't need to touch the remaining tables.

Comment: Hope, you are satisfied with my previous comments & managed to fix your problem. If not, please tell me what problem are you facing? Otherwise please accept an answer. Thanks.

Comment: You are most welcome. Can you please accept an answer?